# Create horizontal scroll by rotating

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to implement a horizontal scroll that works with vertical scroll.

Therefore I created a container and rotated it, same for the content.

```
<div class="horizontal-scroll-wrapper">

  <div class="horizontal-cart">
    <div class="horizontal-image-container">
      <img src="cart.image" class="horizontal-image" alt="cart.title">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

My goal is to have the container fill the whole screen, center all images aligned next to each other (without any margin) and be able to see overflow by scrolling horizontally (when actually scrolling vertically).

You can find my code in the following fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9engubxq/1/